# Why does ASP.NET MVC use Code Access Security?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-access-security

I'm a little curious about why CAS is being extensively used in MVC.  A lot of it seems to be suppressedmessages too.  I may have misunderstood it but I always thought you didn't need to use CAS if you fully trusted the code/server you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS is not used directly by MVC since the MVC binary is security transparent.  If you're looking through the source and are curious, the [SuppressMessage] attributes are just there to tell FxCop not to worry about link demands.